# How to post data to https server in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

So i was building an application in flutter and I came across a problem. 
I need to post JSON data to a https server. Since the application is currently under development so we are using Self-Signed Certificate.

How can I achieve this in dart language?

Below is the code which I use to make single post request to the web server over **http**, but whenever I replace the **http** with **https**(Self Signed) I get an error: 
 HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
 CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate(handshake.cc:355))

```
 var url = 'http://192.168.1.40/registration.php'; //or https
 var data = {"email":"yyyy@xx.com","name":"xyz"};

 http.post(url, body:data)
     .then((response) {
   print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
   print("Response body: ${response.body}");
 }).catchError((error) => print(error.toString()));
```

I am pretty new to Flutter and Dart please help me out. Suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: There are two different HTTP clients: dart:io and package:http. Which are you using? Where are you stuck? the JSON bit, the posting bit, or the certificate trust bit? Maybe show your code and share what isn't working.

Comment: I am working with package:http. How can I use the self signed certificate bypassing the verification ? Changes had been made to the question with code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`http.post` is a convenience wrapper which creates a IOClient under the hood. You can pass your own io HttpClient to this, and that has a way to disable the certificate checks, so you just have to construct them yourself like this...

```
  bool trustSelfSigned = true;
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
    ..badCertificateCallback =
        ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => trustSelfSigned);
  IOClient ioClient = new IOClient(httpClient);
  ioClient.post(url, body:data);

  // don't forget to call ioClient.close() when done
  // note, this also closes the underlying HttpClient
```

the bool `trustSelfSigned` controls whether you get the default behaviour or allows bad certificates.

Comment: forgot to say: you will need to import dart:io to get HttpClient

Comment: There is some change in http package, need to import 'package:http/io_client.dart' to get access to  IOClient.

Answer (score 3):

best way for ssl certification problem on all http request

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main(){
    HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
    runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the self signed certificate to your device. I know IOS is really picky when it comes to certificates. But for development environments I would use just normal HTTP calls. Another thing you can do if the server has it's own domain name (Global. Not local) is using [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). Free SSL certificates for all your projects. And the setup is really easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use bypass certificates whether for web or mobile, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57801629/4458708. In summary,

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/io_client.dart' as ioclient;

var _httpClient = HttpClient();
_httpClient.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
var _ioClient = ioclient.IOClient(_httpClient);
```

and use _ioClient in your requests.