# differences in using or not http.Client

Tags: http, flutter, httpclient

going on Flutter documentation I found that fetching data was done, sometimes, by using `http.Client` and sometimes not (just `http.get` for example). So I was wondering the purpose of using `http.Client`.

These are the two sites where I found this:

https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/

https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/background-parsing/

Comment: It's there for tests purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `http` package uses a default `IOClient` when you use the convenience `http.get` and `http.post` methods. However, sometimes you might want to use a specialized `Client`, for example to change the default HTTPS certificate validation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839729/how-to-post-data-to-https-server-in-dart/49848252#49848252).

In this circumstance, you can create any `Client` subclass and use it in the ways shown in your second link. It's rarely necessary, though so the syntax used in your first link is normally sufficient.