# How to solve Flutter CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error while performing a POST request?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am sending a post request in Dart. It is giving a response when I test it on API testing tools such as Postman. But when I run the app. It gives me the following error:-

```
E/flutter ( 6264): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: E/flutter ( 6264):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:363))
```

Here is my code of the function -

```
Future getAccessToken(String url) async {

    try {
      http.post('url',
          body: {
            "email": "xyz@xyz.example",
            "password": "1234"
          }).then((response) {
        print("Reponse status : ${response.statusCode}");
        print("Response body : ${response.body}");
        var myresponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
        String token = myresponse["token"];
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
```

Here's the full error body:

```
E/flutter ( 6264): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception: E/flutter ( 6264): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: E/flutter ( 6264):   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:363)) E/flutter ( 6264): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23) E/flutter ( 6264): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 6264): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38) E/flutter ( 6264): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 6264): #2     BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:54:7) E/flutter ( 6264): #3      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:70:16) E/flutter ( 6264): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20) E/flutter ( 6264): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 6264): #5     post (package:http/http.dart:69:5) E/flutter ( 6264): #6
_MyLoginFormState.getAccessToken (package:chart/main.dart:74:7) E/flutter ( 6264): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 6264): #7
_MyLoginFormState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:chart/main.dart:64:29)
```

Comment: Do you user a self signed certificate ?

Comment: I just want to accept all certificates

Comment: well, if it a self signed one, it won't work. Dart does not allow self signed certificates. One solution (a bad one imho) is to allow certificates, even invalid ones, but it removes the core principle of using certificates.

Comment: define a class import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';

class TrustAllCertificates {
  static http.Client sslClient() {
    var ioClient = new HttpClient()
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
        return (host.compareTo("domain-name.com") == 0);
      };
    http.Client _client = IOClient(ioClient);

    return _client;
  }
}

Comment: Response response = await TrustAllCertificates.sslClient().get(Url, headers: headers);

Comment: Response response = await TrustAllCertificates.sslClient().get(Url, body: bodyRequest, headers: headers);

Comment: Seems Flutter 2.5.3 solved this issue

Comment: This could happen if the websites ( APIs ) ssl certificate expired.

Answer (score 369, accepted):

In order to enable this option globally in your project, here is what you need to do:

1. In your main.dart file, add or import the following class:

> ```
>  import 'dart:io';
> ```

> ```
>  class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
>   @override
>   HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
>     return super.createHttpClient(context)
>       ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
>   }
> }
> ```

2. In your main function, add the following line after function definition:

> ```
>  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
> ```

Your main.dart should look like this

> ```
> void main() {
>  // Your code
>  
>  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
>   runApp(const ConsultationApp());
> }
> ```

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19588#issuecomment-406779390) comment was very helpful to pass through this matter, **and please note that...**

> **This should be used while in development mode, do ***`NOT`*** do this when you want to release to production, the aim of this answer is to**
> **make the development a bit easier for you, for production, you need to fix your certificate issue and use it properly, look at the other answers for this as it might be helpful for your case.**

Comment: This helped me with a third party lib that does not give access to the http client instance inside. Now it works, thanks

Comment: This solution works perfectly.  In my case it's the typical scenario:  self-signed cert on dev box.

Comment: This will work, but it's effectively disabling security in BoringSSL. If you have a good reason to do that (self-signed certs on a dev box that aren't technically valid), that's good. But be cautious about shipping code like this to a production environment...

Comment: Don't forget to use HttpClient `createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context)` (notice the question mark) for null safety

Comment: on which end this issue is generating ? backend or frontend. What are the permanent possible solutions?

Comment: For null safety users add ? after SecurityContext like `SecurityContext?`

Comment: thankyou its helpfully when the backend on localhost

Comment: @Ma'moon Al-Akash As you mentioned this should not be use on Production, then what solution should for the production?

Comment: @JCKödel Do you have solution regarding this one? I agree with your statement. This just kind of stupidity.

Comment: @Bobby Check the answer here that adds the `lets-encrypt-r3.pem` to Flutter's assets. Usually, root certs are updated in new devices, but, in my case, I had a Moto G 2013 with Android 5.0 (intentionally left un-upgraded for testing reasons) and those devices don't get updates anymore.

Comment: Is there a workaround for flutter web?

Answer (score 98):

1. Download cert from https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-r3.pem
2. Add this file to assets/ca/ Flutter project root directory
3. Add assets/ca/ assets directory in pubspec.yaml
4. Add this code on your app initialization:

   ```
   void main() async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

     ByteData data = await PlatformAssetBundle().load('assets/ca/lets-encrypt-r3.pem');
     SecurityContext.defaultContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());

     runApp(MyApp());
   }
   ```

It works with the default chain, so no changes are needed on the server.
Android < 7.1.1 clients will still have access in a browser context.

Comment: Should use this solution for new devices. Please refer to the update from letsencrypt:
 
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/#:~:text=On%20September%2030%202021%2C%20there,accept%20your%20Let's%20Encrypt%20certificate

Comment: Additionally, I could use my `cert.pem` instead of the expired `lets-encrypt-r3.pem`.

Comment: Where do ByteData, SecurityContext come from?  Is there additional packages need to be installed? Tried this and it says ByteData, SecurityContext, PlatformAssetBundle() not defined.

Comment: import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; for PlatformAssetBundle 
and import 'dart:io'; for SecurityContext

Comment: Is it good for security purpose? Since we are using public certificate

Comment: this solution worked for me... in production I use self signed certificates, so I needed a way to load the certificate and verify it.

Comment: Still error : `Error: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
I/flutter (22925):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:393))` for free fake api : `https://mockland.dev/api/category/list`

Answer (score 55):

If you are using [Dio library](https://pub.dev/packages/dio), just do this:

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
(_dio.httpClientAdapter as IOHttpClientAdapter).createHttpClient = () =>
      HttpClient()
        ..badCertificateCallback =
            (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
```

Comment: i got: ``The name 'DefaultHttpClientAdapter' isn't a type, so it can't be used in an 'as' expression.``

Comment: @Zorro Did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same exception.

Comment: @aanal-mehta yes look at my post at the bottom.

Comment: @Zorro Can you share the link?

Comment: @aanal-mehta i mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285172/how-to-solve-flutter-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-performing-a-post-req/60890158?noredirect=1#answer-66468547

Comment: This is a working solution, for anyone who runs into the error @Zorro mentioned, you need to add `package:dio/adapter.dart` to your imports.

Comment: the latest dio changed from (dio.httpClientAdapter DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate to (dio.httpClientAdapter as IOHttpClientAdapter).createHttpClient which causing error in the body

Comment: **Working code for the latest DIO clieant:**

`(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate = (client) {
  client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  return client;
};`

Answer (score 45):

This Code work for me

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I think it will the same for you...

Comment: this works on mobile, but not on flutter web

Comment: I tried this solution, but It's not worked for the Flutter web.

Comment: Wanna connect to localhost but i made a typo, so i turn `https` into `http`, then worked.

Comment: worked on debug, but not release mode.

Comment: If you want to allow in flutter web, you can enter directly in browser to url of your app and accept manually that certificate

Comment: I get this error message `MyHttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext)') isn't a valid override of 'HttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext?)')`

Answer (score 38):

**Edit & Update Feb 2021:** When this question was earlier asked there were not enough docs and developers to answer. The following answers may be more helpful than this one:
[Ma'moon Al-Akash Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927/9088598), [Pedro Massango's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59303283/9088598) & [Ken's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285172/how-to-solve-flutter-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-performing-a-post-req/66166499#66166499)

If you have not found the solution in these 3 answers, you can try the solution below.

**Originally Answered Jan 2019:**
The correct(but bad) way to do it, as I found out, is to allow all certificates.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

String url ='xyz@xyz.example';

Map map = {
     "email": "email",
     "password": "password"
};

HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');

request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));

HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

print(reply);
```

Comment: by any chance found a better solution about a year later?

Comment: This issue still persists. How would one handle it on production without allowing all certificates?

Answer (score 30):

The best approach (I think so) is to allow certificates for trusted hosts, so if your API host is `"api.my_app"` you can allow certificates from this host only:

```dart
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
     final isValidHost = host == "api.my_app";

     // Allowing multiple hosts
     // final isValidHost = host == "api.my_app" || host == "my_second_host";
     return isValidHost;
    });
```

If you have more hosts you can just add a new check there.

Answer (score 21):

```
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

    Future getAccessToken(String url) async {
      try {
        final ioc = new HttpClient();
        ioc.badCertificateCallback =
            (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
        final http = new IOClient(ioc);
        http.post('url', body: {"email": "xyz@xyz.example", "password": "1234"}).then(
            (response) {
          print("Reponse status : ${response.statusCode}");
          print("Response body : ${response.body}");
          var myresponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
          String token = myresponse["token"];
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

Check the device date and time in device settings. The device date and time is set to previous date.

Comment: One of things you should check first before copying code from other answers.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I agree with it, but i cannot see the same relevant answer in this post.

Answer (score 8):

This is for http library method. here is what you need to do in order to enable this option globally in your project.
[image]

```
    class MyHttpoverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override 
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
    ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=>true;
  }
}

//void main() => runApp(MyApp());
void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global=new MyHttpoverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

for more details:https://fluttercorner.com/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-in-flutter/

Answer (score 7):

Using [Dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for request on my local server with self signed certificat, i prefer to allow a specific host rather than all domains.

```
//import 'package:get/get.dart' hide Response;  //<-- if you use get package
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
        final isValidHost = ["192.168.1.67"].contains(host); // <-- allow only hosts in array
        return isValidHost;
      });
  }
}

// more example: https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/tree/master/example
void getHttp() async {
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  Response response;
  response = await dio.get("https://192.168.1.67");
  print(response.data);
}
```

Comment: createHttpClient isn't a valid override of 'HttpOverrides.createHttpClient'

Comment: @Mr.ZeroOne make the context optional to match the parent. So `createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context)`.

Answer (score 6):

For everyone landing here with a need to solve the problem and not just bypass it allowing everything.

For me the problem solved on the server side (as it should be) with no change in the code. Everything is valid now. On all the other solutions the problem still exists (eg The Postman runs but it displays a configuration error on the globe next to response status)
The configuration is Centos/Apache/LetsEncrypt/Python3.8/Django3.1.5/Mod_wsgi/ but I guess that the solution is valid for most installations of Apache/LetsEncrypt

The steps to resolve are

1. Locate the line "SSLCACertificateFile" on the Virtual Host you wish to config. For example:

> SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/my_ca.crt

2. Download
   https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-r3-cross-signed.txt
   At the end of /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/my_ca.crt (after the -----END CERTIFICATE-----) start a new line and paste from lets-encrypt-r3-cross-signed.txt everything bellow -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- (including -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----)
3. Save /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/my_ca.crt
4. Restart Apache httpd

References:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43575
https://letsencrypt.org/certs

Also you can check the validity of your cert in https://www.digicert.com/help/.

Answer (score 6):

This issue happened to us as we are not using the fullchain.pem generated using let's encrypt on nginx. Once changed that it fixes this issue.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem;
```

For Apache, you might need to configure `SSLCertificateChainFile`. More discussion about the issue `https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50699`

Answer (score 6):

For me, it was because I am using HTTPS and the API uses HTTP so I just changed it to HTTP and it works.

Answer (score 6):

For those who need to ignore certificate errors only for certain calls, you could use the `HttpOverrides` solution already mentioned by numerous answers.

However, there is no need to use it globally. You can use it only for certain calls that you know experience handshake errors by wrapping the call in `HttpOverrides.runWithHttpOverrides()`.

```
class IgnoreCertificateErrorOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
      return true;
    });
  }
}


Future<void> myNonSecurityCriticalApiCall() async {
  await HttpOverrides.runWithHttpOverrides(() async {
    String url = 'https://api.example.com/non/security/critical/service';
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));

    // ... do something with the response ...
  }, IgnoreCertificateErrorOverrides());
}
```

In my case it is an external API which does have a valid SSL certificate and works in the browser but for some reason won't work in my Flutter app.

Comment: Can't edit the answer, the correct null safe way is `HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){`

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was the problem with the android emulator. I just created a new android emulator that fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks. The problem for me was that the Android Emulator was set for the wrong time and date. Resetting the time/date manually solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Dio library,'DefaultHttpClientAdapter' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use IOHttpClientAdapter instead.

first import manually:

```
import 'package:dio/io.dart';
```

then use 'IOHttpClientAdapter' instead of 'DefaultHttpClientAdapter'

```
(_dio.httpClientAdapter as IOHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
      (HttpClient client) {
    client.badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
    return client;
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I figured out that the actual root of the problem was out-of-sync time on my test device...

Answer (score 3):

Actually in my case I fixed it after updating the date and time on my pc. Might help someone I guess

Answer (score 2):

I specifically needed to use `lib/client.dart` `Client` interface for http calls (i.e. http.Client instead of HttpClient) . This was required by `ChopperClient` ([link](https://github.com/lejard-h/chopper)).

So I could not pass `HttpClient` from `lib/_http/http.dart` directly to Chopper.
ChopperClient can receive `HttpClient` in the constructor wrapped in `ioclient.IOClient`.

```
HttpClient webHttpClient = new HttpClient();
webHttpClient.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
dynamic ioClient = new ioclient.IOClient(webHttpClient);
final chopper = ChopperClient(
  baseUrl: "https://example.com",
  client: ioClient,
  services: [
    MfService.create()
  ],
  converter: JsonConverter(),
);
final mfService = MfService.create(chopper);
```

This way you can **temporarily** ignore CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error in your calls. Remember - that's only for development purposes. Don't use this in production environment!

Comment: @kosiara - Bartosz Kosarzycki. I am trying to implement your solution but  I think it would be better with the full code. ioclientIOClient(..) and MfService can't see where they are defined. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update on January 30, 2021:
I know the reason, because nginx is configured with some encryption algorithms that flutter does not support! , The specific need to try.

Use `tls 1.3` request URL, no problem.

Example

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  // tls 1.2 error
//  var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse('https://shop.io.mi-img.com/app/shop/img?id=shop_88f929c5731967cbc8339cfae1f5f0ec.jpeg')); 
  // tls 1.3 normal
  var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse('https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Ud7cd28ffdf6e475c8dc382380d5d1976o.jpg'));
  var response = await request.close();
  print(response.headers);
  client.close(force: true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This Solution is finally worked. Thanks to Milad

```
    final ioc = new HttpClient();
    ioc.badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
    final http = new IOClient(ioc);
    http.post(); //Your Get or Post Request
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the above solutions but nothing worked ...
I figured out that the solutions is there is error with the mobile date/time zone. the time zone used is not at my country time zone. I changed it and it worked. !!!

Answer (score 1):

***Note:** If this error occurs other than trying to connect to a local SSL please fix it correctly and don't just use `badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) => true` as it is a security risk!*

But.. if you run into this issue because you want to connect to a local back-end running a self signed certificate you could do the following.

You can use this client to connect to sources other then you local back-end.

```dart
class AppHttpClient {
  AppHttpClient({
    Dio? client,
  }) : client = client ?? Dio() {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      // this.client.interceptors.add(PrettyDioLogger());
    }
  }
  final Dio client;
}
```

You can use this client to connect to your local back-end. Make sure you set the `--dart-define FLAVOR=development` flag when running your app.

```dart
class InternalApiHttpClient extends AppHttpClient {
  ApiHttpClient({
    super.client,
    required this.baseUrl,
  }) {
    _allowBadDevelopmentCertificate();
  }

  void _allowBadDevelopmentCertificate() {
    const flavor = String.fromEnvironment('FLAVOR');
    if (flavor == 'development') {
      final httpClientAdapter =
          super.client.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter;
      httpClientAdapter.onHttpClientCreate = (client) {
        return client..badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) => true;
      };
    }
  }

  final Uri baseUrl;
}
```

Doing it this way only suppresses the certificate message when you are on your development environment only when connecting to your local API. Any other requests stay untouched and if failing should be solved in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the emulator. So ensure that your date and time are right. Because in my case I found that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by generating the full_chain.crt file.

You might have received the your_domain.crt file and your_domain.ca-bundle file. Now what you have to do is combine the crt file and ca-bundle file to generate the crt file.

```
cat domain.crt domain.ca-bundle >> your_domain_full_chain.crt
```

Then you just need to put the your_domain_full_chain.crt file in the nginx and it will start working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to remake my backend's ssl certs. I had generated the certs using mkcert and just had to make new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If the other suggestions are not helpful here is another way. After updating SSL certificate of web site from goDaddy, all https API requests in Android device retured this exception:

```
I/flutter (23473): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
I/flutter (23473):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))
```

It causes an issue only in Flutter app running in Android. iOS app still works without any problem.

Serverside solution without changing anything in the app is to concatenate your domain’s certificate file and certificate authorities chain file and to include the bundled certificate-file into nginx config.

It happens because  certificate authorities certificate is  provided as a .pem-file for using in Apache2 vhost-config like this:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain.pem
```

However, for using it in nginx we need to merge them like below:

```
cat example.org.crt chain.pem > bundle.crt
ssl_certificate bundle.crt
```

And use the result file in nginx.

Details [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50699#issuecomment-989025787) and [here](https://blog.steven266.de/include-a-certificate-chain-file-in-nginx-6dca9acdcbb6).

Answer (score 0):

We have same problem. In the result we added all ssl-tokens to one file on the server and it started work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using http.Client() from import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
we can use this function

```
import "dart:io";
import "package:http/io_client.dart";
IOClient getClient() {
final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient(context: context)
 ..badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
final client = IOClient(httpClient);
client.get(Uri.parse(PSApp.config!.liveUrl!));
return client;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not, please check the server also With which you want to hit the API!

> Or if everything is fine there then you can use this!

```
HttpOverrides
```

your problem will be solved!

Answer (score -1):

For the record, in my case it was as simple as deactivating the anti-virus.
It is a simple to try tip.

Answer (score -4):

If you use Android Emulator I've found out that this occurs when there is no internet connection. Check that your emulator has a network connection!

Comment: That has nothing to do with internet connection, it's an issue with https: secure http connection. I tthink the best sol so far is, as suggested in many answers above, is to cretae a badCertificateCallback  that bypass certficate verification