# How to handle cors for web flutter

Tags: flutter, cors, x509certificate, flutter-web

I have been struggle to fix the `cors` problem in my `PWA` project of `flutter` and I am following this

> [how to solve flutter CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error while performing a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285172/how-to-solve-flutter-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-performing-a-post-req..).

I am using `universal_io` package since dart.io can not be used for web...here is the part of the code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.badCertificateCallback =
          ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
      String url = 'https:xxxx.php';
      Map map = {
        "a": "a",
        "b": "b"
      };
      HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
      request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));
      if (request is BrowserHttpClientRequest) {
        request.credentialsMode = BrowserHttpClientCredentialsMode.include;
      }
      HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
      print(response.toString());
      String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      print(reply);
```

but I get the error that say like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BrowserHttpClient received an error from XMLHttpRequest (which doesn't tell
reason for the error).
HTTP method:        POST
URL:                https://www.rscm.co.id/apirscm/v2.php
Origin:             http://localhost:64121
Cross-origin request!
XmlHttpRequest 'credentials mode' is enabled.
Did the server send the following mandatory headers?
  * Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  * Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:64121
    * In credentials mode, '*' would fail!
  * Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
```

is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: i think the Dio package solved this problem on web..But still not sure

Comment: Hi, yhank you for your suggestion I will try to use Dio package too

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430093/flutter-web-accessing-url-image-cors-policy/72430315#72430315:~:text=You%20can%20mock%20the%20calls%20from%20any%20other%20endpoint%20which%20allows%20all%20cross%20origins%20like%20I%20have%20used%20the%20following%2C) article.

Answer (score 2):

You can you local host server in the debug mode of chrome, here is how:
open this in terminal.

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/Users/i0868/Desktop/Chrome" --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I will try it and I would like to know....is it only for debug mode and after I deploy my web project... am I still geting cors issue?

Comment: yes there is a chance it will happen....you have to configure you backend to  Allow-Control-Allow-Origin...we did the same thing in our team..there i nothing can't be done from flutter side

Comment: Okey, let me try your answer first...thank you very much for your help

Comment: `open` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like thisto enable credentials mode:

```
final httpClientRequest = MyHttpClientRequest;
if (httpClientRequest is BrowserHttpClientRequest) {
  httpClientRequest.credentialsMode = BrowserHttpClientCredentialsMode.include;
}
```

But prefer using this librairy [universal_io](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io) instead of dart.io

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I end up with configure the backend to Allow-Control-Allow-Origin and it works well