# Flutter Web Accessing URL Image CORS policy

Tags: flutter, image, security, web, cors

In my flutter web when I'm trying to show network image, I'm getting an error of CORS.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-network-image-url.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:63785' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Its working properly in my Android/iOS Mobile Apps.

I already fetch same issue in my backend php api.
At that time adding headers in php file solve the issue.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,content-type");
```

I'm confuse how to add header in image get request.

Sorry If I'm asking same question again.
But I could not find proper solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the calls from any other endpoint which allows all cross origins like I have used the following,

```
String allowCORSEndPoint = "https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=";
```

And while making a call you can use a a variable like this,

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

http.Response response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(allowCORSEndPoint + url),
);
```

Comment: Whats this link does? Is it possible for me to create my own link on my php server or anything?

Comment: Even I want to figure that out and write my own thing on my spring boot application.. Been occupied hence its just in my pipeline for now..
Anyways, if you find any thing, do share accross..