# Why do devices with expired SSL certificates keep working?

Tags: android, ssl

I noticed that our app stopped working on a test device under Android 6. After researching, I found that this is due to the fact that the certificate has expired.

more here [Flutter on Android 7 CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with LetsEncrypt SSL cert after Sept 30, 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511057/flutter-on-android-7-certificate-verify-failed-with-letsencrypt-ssl-cert-after-s)

At the same time, according to the analytics, devices with 5 and 6 Androids continue to work. Why is this happening? As far as I understand, the certificate was supposed to expire on October 1, 2021, and all devices with old OSes should have lost the ability to work with our backend.

PS even more diligent is that exactly the same devices with the same OS version as my test device are working

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"?

Answer (score -1):

Even tho the certificate has expired it doesn't mean that you can't communicate with the backend, it will just mean that the connection won't be https and will be http instead.

Haven't released anything on mobile yet so not 100% sure as to how it works on there but I think my above statement is what happens.

Comment: No, that's not what happens. If you try to make an https connection and the certificate is expired the connection will fail, period. The client can be configured to ignore the expiration problem but that certainly doesn't mean the connection becomes HTTP.