# Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:393))

Tags: android, flutter, dart, ssl, post

I launch my app on older version of Android - 5.1 and I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:393))
```

On newer Android like 10 this is not appearing.
I am making POST request to my backend, how to fix it?

I found solution: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511057/flutter-on-android-7-certificate-verify-failed-with-letsencrypt-ssl-cert-after-s)

Comment: certificate has expired!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one

```
   class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I am not sure about flutter web but it may help flutter ios and android.

Comment: I am using the suggested solution, but I am getting this error: "MyHttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext)') isn't a valid override of 'HttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext?)')."
which got solved by -->
Change SecurityContext to SecurityContext?.