# I get an error while I send the following http get request. I use flutter 2.5

Tags: flutter, http, get

Here is the line of code the causes the error

```
var currencyData = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/BTC/USD?apikey=------------------------'));
```

Here is the error log

```
E/flutter (20209): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter (20209):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:359))
E/flutter (20209): #0      _SecureFilterImpl._handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:101:69)
E/flutter (20209): #1      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:143:25)
E/flutter (20209): #2      _RawSecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:794:54)
E/flutter (20209): #3      _RawSecureSocket._tryFilter (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:924:19)
E/flutter (20209): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20209): 
D/mali_winsys(20209): new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
D/libEGL  (20209): eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xd867f7c4
I/OpenGLRenderer(20209): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/mali_winsys(20209): new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
I/Timeline(20209): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@a6bd033 time:158054628
E/flutter (20209): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter (20209):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:359)), stack trace: #0      _SecureFilterImpl._handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:101:69)
E/flutter (20209): #1      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:143:25)
E/flutter (20209): #2      _RawSecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:794:54)
E/flutter (20209): #3      _RawSecureSocket._tryFilter (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:924:19)
E/flutter (20209): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20209):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a https protocol issue. Since the url is working fine, is more like that there is a problem with your device. Trying adjust its clock may fix this problem because https needs both, client and sever, to have the same current time.
If this problem persists, try to run your code in a different device.

Comment: i ran it on another device and it worked. Is there any way to run it on my own device? I really need to run it on this device.

Comment: You may try this solution to fix this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927/5818075