# badCertificateCallback function of HttpClient get the wrong type

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to fix `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` (in development mode), it seems this answer is good https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927/8010101, so i tried it, but this error show up

> A value of type 'bool Function(X509Certificate, String, int)' can't be
> assigned to a variable of type 'bool Function(X509Certificate, String,
> int)?'.

this is my code from `main.dart`

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with the code you've shown.  The error message, assuming you copied and pasted it exactly, does not make any sense (unless you somehow have multiple types named `X509Certificate`, `String`, or `int`).  I copied and pasted your code and cannot reproduce your problem.  Can you provide a *complete* example that reproduces it?

Comment: i don't know what is the problem, when i put that code in the main.dart file, the error show up, but when i put it in new file, it work fine

Comment: Show the rest of your `main.dart` file.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for trying to help, the problem in main.dart because of import `flutter_inappwebview` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem when I imported inappwebview to main.dart.

What helped me is changing the import to:

```
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart' as inapp;
```

And when I use inappwebview:

```
await inapp.InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```