# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED although it should be valid?

Tags: flutter, dart, security, ssl, certificate

do you know by any chance why the badCertificateCallback is being called? The certificate (that dart is claiming to be invalid) is exactly the same that I have set up as trusted certificate (the equality check is true!).

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';

final PEM = new File(
  '../server_keys/cert.pem',
).readAsBytesSync();

Future<http.Response> listDir(String path) async {
  SecurityContext context = new SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false);

  context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(PEM);

  print("context setup");
  final httpClient = HttpClient(context: context);

  httpClient.badCertificateCallback = ((cert, host, port) {
    print("In bad certificate callback.");
    print('Subject: ${cert.subject}');
    print('Issuer: ${cert.issuer}');
    print('Expires: ${cert.endValidity}');
    print('Host: ${host}');
    print('Port: ${port}');
    return String.fromCharCodes(PEM) == cert.pem;
  });

  print("get url");

  final client = IOClient(httpClient);
  print("POSTING");
  return client
      .post(
        Uri.parse('https://127.0.0.1:5000/list'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'path': path,
        }),
      )
      .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));
}

void main() async {
  await listDir("admin/user/test").then((response) {
    print(response.body);
  });
  print("finished");
}
```

Furthermore, this is working just fine:

```bash
curl -v --cacert ../server_keys/cert.pem https://127.0.0.1:5000/list
```

Maybe you can give me an hint.

### Further information:

Here is the certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Here is the python flask server code (now with localhost):

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import ssl

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/list", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def list_route():
    return jsonify(isError= False,
                    message= "Success",
                    statusCode= 200,
                    data={
                        "path": "hihi"
                    }), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    server_keys = {
        "url": "localhost",
        "cert_file": "server_keys/cert.pem",
        "key_file": "server_keys/key.pem",
    }
    os.system("openssl req -x509 -nodes -new -sha256 -days 390 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server_keys/key.pem -out server_keys/cert.pem -subj '/C=de/CN=localhost'")
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)    
    context.load_cert_chain(server_keys["cert_file"], server_keys["key_file"])    
    app.run(debug=True, ssl_context=context, host=server_keys["url"], port="5000")
```

It is working with curl:

```bash
curl -v --cacert ../server_keys/cert.pem https://localhost:5000/list
```

But still not for me with dart (using Intel Mac OSX Monetary).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-solve-flutter-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-performing-a-post-req](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69481863/2828341)

Comment: Using:
```
  SecurityContext.defaultContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(PEM);
  final httpClient = HttpClient();
```
gives me the same behavior :(

Comment: Does the certificate match the URL, i.e. has this certificate a subject alternative name for 127.0.0.1? Could you please provide the full certificate so one could have a look at the certificate details? Specifically, does the certificate has basic constraints CA:true  or CA:false?

Comment: I have not deliberately added any constraints. I added the certificate to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've stumbled upon a bug on Dart. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35462) about this exact problem. It only appears on macOS but on Windows/Linux/Android it works flawlessly...

Below is the command to generate the keys in `bash`. I've tested the script on my own and it works on Windows but fails on macOS.

```bash
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT \
  -config <(printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Comment: could you share with me how you created the certificate? For me I still get the same "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" error even with localhost...
Do I create the keys in a wrong way? e.g. I just tried this: openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out server_keys/cert.pem -keyout server_keys/key.pem -days 731 -sha256 -subj "/CN=localhost"

Comment: I've added the info to the answer itself. Please take a look

Comment: thank you very much. I just tested it but somehow the dart code is just timing out on me :( What OS are you using? Curl is working again without issue...

Comment: Testing on macOS the problem also shows for me (I was testing on Windows). Looks like you've stumbled upon a bug on Dart. Please check my answer again with the updated info.

Answer (score 1):

Just my experience:

Although everything regarding *SecurityContext* was in place, with correct formats of key/cert/ca-cert (I'm configuring mTLS), although it worked on Android, it did not on iOS; it failed with error:

[image: screenshot of error]

After couple days of pain, I've found Apple's requirement for trusted certificates and, in the end, that resolved my issue: https://support.apple.com/en-au/103769