# Flutter cached_network_image Handshake error

Tags: flutter

we force https on our backend server, after it images used by cached_network_image returns errors:

```
Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))
```

My code (works ok before force https):

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: addr,
          progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) =>
              CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
                  value: downloadProgress.progress),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
          httpHeaders: RuntimeMetadata.getTokenAsWholeMap());
```

Comment: Refer this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927/19976446)

Answer (score 4):

In your main.dart file, add or import the following class:

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
      @override
      HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
        return super.createHttpClient(context)
          ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
      }
    }
```

then call this in main()

```
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```