# DioError HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:393))

Tags: android, ios, flutter, https, dio

`E/flutter (17310): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:  E/flutter (17310):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:393)) E/flutter (17310): Source stack: E/flutter (17310): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35) E/flutter (17310): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12) E/flutter (17310): #2      DioMixin.get (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:61:12) E/flutter (17310): #3      getState (package:land_resource_inventory/modules/home/view/home_page.dart:355:28) E/flutter (17310): #4      _onTileClicked (package:land_resource_inventory/modules/home/view/home_page.dart:345:7) E/flutter (17310): #5      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:land_resource_inventory/modules/home/view/home_page.dart:232:40) E/flutter (17310): #6      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072:21) E/flutter (17310): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24) E/flutter (17310): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11) E/flutter (17310): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5) E/flutter (17310): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:276:7) E/flutter (17310): #11     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:163:27) E/flutter (17310): #12     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:464:20) E/flutter (17310): #13     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:22) E/flutter (17310): #14     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:337:11) E/flutter (17310): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395:7) E/flutter (17310): #16     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357:5) E/flutter (17310): #17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314:7) E/flutter (17310): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7) E/flutter (17310): #19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167:13) E/flutter (17310): #20     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341:7) E/flutter (17310): #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31) E/flutter (17310):  E/flutter (17310): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:643:7) E/flutter (17310): #1      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1658:54) E/flutter (17310): #2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22) E/flutter (17310): #3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47) E/flutter (17310): #4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13) E/flutter (17310): #5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5) E/flutter (17310): #6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12) E/flutter (17310): #7      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:23:5) E/flutter (17310): #8      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:617:45) E/flutter (17310): #9      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1658:54) E/flutter (17310): #10     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22) E/flutter (17310): #11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47) E/flutter (17310): #12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13) E/flutter (17310): #13     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5) E/flutter (17310): #14     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:665:7) E/flutter (17310): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21) E/flutter (17310): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)`

I have already tried:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927/1776243

Comment: Please explain your problem. The posted error is ambiguous without details like what you are trying to achieve, what your development environment is, and where you are getting the error.

Comment: Why are you using an expired certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not recommended in production scenarios, you can accept any certificates by overriding the HttpClient that dio uses by providing a onHttpClientCreate, like the following :

```
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate  = (client) {
  client.badCertificateCallback=(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port){
      return true;
  };
};
```

Again, only use this for debugging and development purposes. In production, you should use a valid SSL certificate.

Documentation for [onHttpClientCreate](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/adapter/DefaultHttpClientAdapter/onHttpClientCreate.html)