# Can't use DiceBears with Flutter NetworkImage

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following HandshakeException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Handshake error in client (OS Error:
        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:393))

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _SecureFilterImpl._handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:99:46)
#1      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:142:25)
#2      _RawSecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:911:54)
#3      _RawSecureSocket._tryFilter (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:1040:19)
<asynchronous suspension>

Image provider: NetworkImage("https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/micah/your-custom-seed.jpg", scale:
  1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/micah/your-custom-seed.jpg", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I was trying to integrate profile pictures into my Flutter app.

```
    CircleAvatar(
          // TODO username, color integration with api
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              'https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/micah/your-custom-seed.jpg'),
          radius: 17.0,
          // backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Flutter CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED error while performing a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285172/how-to-solve-flutter-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-performing-a-post-req)

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection, I totally forgot to just google HandshakeException which leads me to [this StackOverflow reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927/13754957) that has the solution that worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).