# Network Image doesnt load on older android versions (I believe)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im retrieving data from an api which includes a photo, which I show using NetworkImage, when using an emulator with android 9.0 "Pie", this works perfectly fine, but when i use an emulator with android 7.0 "Nougat" and a physical device again with android 7.0 "Nougat", they both dont load these images

`Image(image: NetworkImage("${widget.teamphoto}"), height: 75, width: 75,), Center( child: CircleAvatar( backgroundImage: NetworkImage("${widget.photo}"), radius: 60.0, ), ),`

I have internet access turned on also by having `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in my AndoroidManifest.xml

Comment: Is there any error messages from the log? Also check if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927/13625293) fixes the issue (but please note it's only for development purpose)